# Configure UART GPS module for Friendlyarm nanopc-t1 on Android

Tags: adb, gps

have a NanoPC-t1 device and I'm running Android 4.2.2 on it. I want to install my gy-gps6MV2 module and make it work as the device GPS.

Do I need root access? (I already tried to root device with SuperOneClick) I've pluged it into my UART serial port, when I run: adb shell root@android:/ # cat /dev/ttySAC0

All I get is white space outputs, while I know it's the gps module output but I can't figure out why I get white spaces.

When I connect my GPS module via a rs232 to usb I can read the GPS data like a charm (using cat /dev/ttySAC0)

What am I missing? please help me fix this problem, I'm struggling with it for two weeks...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was originating from NanoPC-t1 config which used the USART port for output debug. It was over-writing the gps output.

I used [Android Serial Port API](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid-serialport-api%2F&ei=TmYRVMbOJMfUauH0gfAO&usg=AFQjCNF5_H1_eyhX4PxubFmF61gaCKnAzA&sig2=PkSQMmh_fFw0_MiMDI0nMw&bvm=bv.74894050,d.d2s), and rooted my device. Because accessing ttySAC0 port, needs root access.

I wrote my own NMEA parser to receive GPS fixes.